JWT authentication not working in django rest framework
I have the following project urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('api/token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),
    path("application/", include("application.urls")),
]

settings.py file:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'application',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'rest_framework'
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ( 
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ) 
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=30),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=2),
}

app urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PlaylistViews.as_view()),
    path('api/playlist/get_all_playlists/', PlaylistViews.get_all_playlists, name='get_all_playlists'),
]

PlaylistModel.py:
class Playlist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'playlists'

PlaylistViews.py:
class PlaylistViews(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request):
        content = {'message': 'Hello, World!'}
        return Response(content)
    
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            serializer = PlaylistSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response({'message': 'Playlist added successfully.', 'data': serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response({'message': 'Failed to add playlist.', 'errors': serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except Exception as error:
            return Response({'error': str(error)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

    @api_view(['GET'])
    def get_all_playlists(request):
        try:
            playlists = Playlist.objects.all()
            serializer = PlaylistSerializer(playlists, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        except Exception as error:
            return Response({'error': str(error)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

When i call the following api: http://localhost:8000/api/token/, i am getting the token, and when i use it in any other api call i get the following error: "Authentication credentials were not provided."
However, i am sending the token in the Authorization as bearer token in postman.

here I can see you set Prefix of token AUTH_HEADER_TYPES = JWT you need to change Bearer instead of JWT,
everything is ok just change  'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',) instead of 'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',)

Try with below JWT auth settings
# JWT Settings
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=20),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',), # < --- Need to change
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
    'TOKEN_USER_CLASS': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

}

Test using POSTMAN


when i changed the AUTH_HEADER_TYPES it worked as expected. Thank you
